# How to create a user row if one is not present, not creating with function create()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my code that authenticates against `ldap` and then checks if `ldap user` is in my sql DB

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # require 'byebug'
  def create
    username = params[:nome]
    password = params[:password]

byebug
    if AuthenticateUser.new(username, password).call
      # user = User.create_with(NumeroEmpregado: number)
      # user.save
      # user2 = User.find_or_create_by(nome: username)
      user = User.where("nome = '#{username}'").first
        if user.present?
          session[:user_id] = user.id
          redirect_to '/'
        else 
            user = User.new({NumeroEmpregado: "999", nome: username})
      user.save
          session[:user_id] = user.id
          redirect_to '/'
        end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Erro!              \nNúmero de Empregado e/ou password incorrecto(a)"
      redirect_to '/login'
     end
  end
end
```

but the `user = User.create` is not working and `User.where` is returning user present when there is no user present, what is wrong with my code? I've gone through various iterations of this code but none seem to work and get the following error in line `user.save`

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SessionsController#create
>   TinyTds::Error: Write to the server failed: BEGIN TRANSACTION

full trace error:

```
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (5.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:278:in `execute'
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (5.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:278:in `raw_connection_do'
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (5.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:219:in `block in do_execute'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (5.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:219:in `do_execute'
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (5.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:45:in `begin_db_transaction'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:133:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:158:in `new'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:158:in `begin_transaction'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:22:in `create'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

In my rails console, it just says begin transaction and gives me the same error:

```
irb(main):004:0> username = "nogger"
=> "nogger"
irb(main):005:0> user = User.new({NumeroEmpregado: "999", nome: username})
  SQL (0.0ms)  USE [sqlserverapp]
=> #<User id: nil, NumeroEmpregado: "999", nome: "nogger", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):006:0>           user.save
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION

      SQL (1.0ms)  USE [sqlserverapp]
  User Exists (1.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  1 AS one FROM [users] WHERE [users].[NumeroEmpregado] = @0 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_WS   ORDER BY [users].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 nvarchar(max), @1 int', @0 = N'999', @1 = 1  [["NumeroEmpregado", nil], ["LIMIT", nil]]
=> false

user model:

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_password
has_many :sheets
has_many :tarefa
has_many :estatisticas

validates :NumeroEmpregado, uniqueness:true


end
```

migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :NumeroEmpregado
      t.string :nome
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `username = params[:nome]` a typo?

Comment: Instead `create`, use `new` + `save` - it will give you an error describing what's wrong.

Comment: @Abdulaziz, no and gotqn already tried that.

Comment: @gotqn with User.save: undefined method `save' for #<Class:0x573f6f0>

Comment: Just use, `create!` instead cause it raises an exception if validations fails.

Comment: @gotqn `TinyTds::Error: Write to the server failed: BEGIN TRANSACTION`

Comment: Show the full error message.  Does the `NumeroEmpregado ` column exist?

Comment: @pascalbetz added full trace on question

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL statement? What happens if you just create a user on the console? Do you have any uniqueness constraints on the DB (username column?) that could raise that error?

Comment: @pascalbetz `irb(main):004:0> username = "nogger"
=> "nogger"
irb(main):005:0> user = User.new({NumeroEmpregado: "999", nome: username})
  SQL (0.0ms)  USE [sqlserverapp]
=> #<User id: nil, NumeroEmpregado: "999", nome: "nogger", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):006:0>           user.save
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION`

Comment: Can you add this to the question, it's a bit hard to read. What does the call to `save` return?

Comment: @pascalbetz I did

Comment: return value of save?
do you have an uniqueness constraint?

Comment: what do you mean @pascalbetz

Comment: I am afraid i odnt understand what yo mean

Comment: How did you cretae the Database Table? Do you have a Rails Migration for it?

Comment: Sorry... just saw the "the same things happens in the console". So please ignore my question about the return value.

Comment: Can you run `User.new(nome: 'test', NumeroEmpregado: '999').valid?` and show the output

Comment: @pascalbetz added to question

Comment: Looks like your DB connection is broken. Is the DB up and running? Can you connect? Can you read? `User.first`?

Comment: @pascalbetz had to restart rails consople, checke dit

Comment: Please show your model and the corresponding Migration.

Comment: @pascalbetzcheck edit

Comment: @pascalbetz check edit

Comment: remove the uniqueness validation, try again.

Comment: also: any special gems? pagination or so?

Comment: activerecord-sqlserver-adapter @pascalbetz

Comment: @pascalbetz ArgumentError (You need to supply at least one validation):

Comment: The whole `validates` line

Comment: `validates :NumeroEmpregado` you told me to remove `, uniqueness:true` now it gives me the validation error

Comment: What is the exact error if you remove the line.

Comment: @pascalbetz  ArgumentError (You need to supply at least one validation)

Comment: If you remove the whole line, then you get the "You need to supply at least one validation" error?

Comment: @DandoMandoNogger be aware that `User.where("nome = '#{username}'").first` is an SQL Injection ready to be exploited for full db access. It should be `User.where(nome: username.to_s).first`

Answer (score 3):

From the back and forth in the comments: It looks like the uniqueness validation line creates a invalid SQL statement. Try removing the whole line. If this helps we can continue to figure our why this happens.

Some more recommendations:

You should use `find_by(:nome, username)` instead of `where`

`where` will always return a non-nil value (a `ActiveRecord::Relation`) and you need to call `first`, whereas `find_by` will return either the `User` or `nil`

Then you should NEVER interpolate parameters into a SQL query (the `"'#{username}'"` part of your code). This is dangerous and allows SQL injection or parameters that will break your code.

Then you can use `create!` to raise an exception if creation fails (and you need to rescue that exception to handle the error case). Or you could check the return value of the `create` call.

Also it is common in ruby to use snake_case, so you should call your `NumeroEmpregado` attribute `numero_empregado`

Answer (score 0):

Try set the password on the new user record. I found that you defined

```
password = params[:password]
```

and never used it.